# Multiple loadmovie() ends up with multiple videos played at the same time!

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

i use loadmovie() to load youtube videos inside my flash website but when i load another video the old one doesn't stop, so i tried unloadmovie to destroy it but it seems that i did a mistake in my code

This is how the code looks to stop the old one an load the new:

```
vloader.unloadMovie();
vloader.loadMovie("http://www.youtube.com/v/Alw5hs0chj0&hl=fr&fs=1hJ-mPcGtC");
```

How to do that? please don't suggest me to use other objects or classes, i only want to edit that code.

Note: I have an empty MOVIE CLIP called "vloader" where i load the video player.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try manually calling .stop() first.

Answer (score 0):

Is this both AS2 and AS3 files in your project ?

**From Adobe's Site :** http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application_04.html

> Loading images and SWF files is no
>   longer handled using the **loadMovie**
>   method or MovieClipLoader class.
>   Instead, use the URLRequest class and
>   the Loader class to accomplish the
>   same task.
>
> The following code shows the bare
>   bones of an image loader [Dropped in your youtube link] script:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/v/Alw5hs0chj0&hl=fr&fs=1hJ-mPcGtC");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(request);
addChild(loader);
```

Unless you really do not want to work with API's...

You should check
**YouTube ActionScript 3.0 Player API Reference**

Good Luck !